# How to redirect to a external url in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this function :

```
    $this->loadModel("EstProdutoCpl");

    $foto = $this->EstProdutoCpl->find('first', array('fields'=> array('caminho_foto'), 'conditions' => array('cd_cpl' => $id)));

    if(!empty($foto['EstProdutoCpl']['caminho_foto'])){
        $this->set('foto', $foto['EstProdutoCpl']['caminho_foto']);
    }else{
        echo "<p align='center'>Produto sem foto cadastrada !</p>";
    }
```

And my view :
`<img src="<?php $foto ?>">`

Just to show one image.

$foto has the path that is `C:\wamp\www\pedidoOnline\app\webroot\img\upload\1432135612.png`

How to show the image to the user ?

Only shows a "broke image"..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in the full path you have there:

```
C:\wamp\www\pedidoOnline\app\webroot\img\upload\1432135612.png
```

your cakePHP application has it's webroot at:

```
C:\wamp\www\pedidoOnline\app\webroot
```

you should be able to show your image with an URL that looks like this:

```
/img/upload/1432135612.png
```

Answer (score 1):

The path

```
C:\wamp\www\pedidoOnline\app\webroot\img\upload\1432135612.png
```

is your directory path no one can access it from the web

In cakephp use path like this

```
$this->webroot.'/img/upload/1432135612.png';
```

And don't store full path of image in database because if you migrate your file to another folder or if you change your domain name then it will be problematic.

So try to store image name only because the path img/upload is static so don't have to store the and $this->webroot will gives the path to webroot folder.

So Save image name only to database and do like this

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->webroot ?>img/upload/<?php echo $foto ?>">
```

this will give path something like this

http://domain/path_to_cakephp/img/upload/1432135612.png';